# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDate' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

getting this error when tried to increment the expiry date from date.now

```
discount.expiry.setDate(Date.now() + 1);
```

here discount is the schema and expiry is field.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `discount.expiry` is `undefined`. You need to first figure out why it's `undefined` and then try to set the date.

Comment: so i should have to assign something to expiry like date.now or something

Answer (score 2):

you discount.expiry not have setDate method, it will run if :

```
discount.expiry = new Date();
discount.expiry.setDate(Date.now() + 1);
```

Comment: Ty for response!!! but when i console log discount.expiry then it showing invalid date

Answer (score 1):

Before `setDate` initiate the variable

```
discount.expiry = new Date();
discount.expiry.setDate(discount.expiry.getDate() + 1);
```

Hope this will help you